# Save a variable inside groovy in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, blazemeter

I have a loop controller in which I'm generating a random number for the loop count using groovy. (the below image)

[image]

Is there anyway I can save this "val" variable in this groovy command (I don't want to use a sampler)?

I tried `vars.putObject("val", val)` and `vars.put("val", val.toString())` but they don't work. (the loop does not work at all, so I assume groovy does not understand vars.put?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something "doesn't work" first of all check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

Groovy "understands" `vars.put` however there is a nuance: if you have a comma inside a [JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you need to escape it with a backslash so you need to do something like:

```
vars.putObject('val'\, val)
```

full function just in case:

```
${__groovy(val = (int) Math.round(new Random().nextGaussian() * 0.11 + 0.01); val = val < 0 ? 0 : val; vars.putObject('val'\, val),)}
```

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)